# Filter references based on citation within certain sections using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Is it possible to use BibLaTeX's filtering mechanism to generate a references listing, which are only cited in a particular section of a document, but not in the rest of it? When starting to write my thesis, I compiled a list of references that I have to cite. Now I want to ensure that I did not forget any of them, ideally by letting BibLaTeX list those which are not cited elsewhere.

Comment: Something like that *should* be possible, can you show us an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of your document/bibliography setup so that we have something to play around with? You may also want to look into refsections and refsegments. It would greatly help if you could show the expected outcome of a small mock-up example. (Think of corner cases!)

Comment: Unfortunately, the hand-in deadline is approaching soon. While I was unable to achieve the filtering I intended, I simply added my listing of essential references at the end of my thesis. By selecting the numeric style, I can simply check the citation numbers in the listing. A threshold number can be found, where all citations having a higher number are never cited in the main text of the thesis.

Comment: Still, if you are interested in an answer after the storm has passed, an update of the question with more details would still be appreciated.

Comment: Any news here? The question is a bit vague for a proper answer. The standard mechanisms of `refsection` and `refsegment`s have already been mentioned in the comments.